# Wrapping Text Inside List Element JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to wrap every text inside a list element with a  tag.
The following code only ever changes the last list element.
I can't seem to figure it out.

jQuery:

```
var boxlistAr = jQuery('ul.box-list li').toArray();

for (var i = 0; i < boxlistAr.length; i++){
    var text = jQuery(boxlistAr[i]).text();
    jQuery(boxlistAr[i]).html('<span class="li-text">'+text+'</span>');
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="box-list">
              <li><span class="li-text">Inspirational opening ceremony</li>
              <li><span class="li-text">Safety briefing</li>
              <li><span class="li-text">Equipment tuning</li>
              <li><span class="li-text">Luggage drop</li>
              <li><span class="li-text">Refreshment pitstops every 20-30k</li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: My original code actually, works I must of been delusional when I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method.

```
$("ul.box-list li").wrap($("<span>").addClass("li-text"))
```